# Is there a way to create a global listener to receive messages from a Java websocket?

Tags: java, angularjs, websocket, ionic-framework

I'm working with AngularJS, Ionic and Java as backend. I'm using websocket to create a realtime chat.

I want to set up a listener to receive all the messages anywhere in my app to handler it and keep it without nodejs.

Is there a way to do it that?

Comment: are you using Tomcat? take a look at [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html)

Comment: Sure. I am using tomcat, I have created a websocket. The problem is I am able to manage the messages that I receive from the websocket only in a view. I want to be able to manage all messages in the whole project

Comment: Have you tried a module like https://github.com/wilk/ng-websocket for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a well prepared way to meet such requirements in Java WebSocket API. (Although, it would be possible with JMX without a little bit of effort.) However you can simply do that by writing a parent endpoint class, having every endpoint class extend it like the following:

```
// Assumes you use some dependency injection framework
@Component 
// Your own POJO to be notified of every socket events
public class WebSocketListener {
    public void onOpen(String id) {
        // Your logic here
    }

    public void onMessage(String id, Object message) {
        // Your logic here
    }

    public void onClose(String id) {
        // Your logic here
    }
}

// A parent class to notify your own global listener
// Extend it if you want to listen socket's event through some specific path
public abstract class NotifiableEndpoint {
    @Inject
    private WebSocketListener listener;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        listener.onOpen(session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, StringOrByteBuffer data) {
        listener.onOpen(session.getId(), data);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void OnClose(Session session) {
        listener.onOpen(session.getId());
    }
}

// A concrete class to write your business logic
@ServerEndpoint("/hello")
public class YourEndpoint extends NotifiableEndpoint {
    // Your logic
}
```

Not to use inheritance, reflection through [ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.getEndpointInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#getEndpointInstance(java.lang.Class)) might work.